# System.IO.IOException: A device attached to the system is not functioning when doing File.Copy C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `FileHelper` class which wraps `File.Copy` and does some logging when exceptions occur in a WinForms .NET 4.5.1 app:

```
public static class FileHelper
{
    public static bool TryCopy(string source, string destination, bool overwrite)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(source, destination, overwrite);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"Copying file from {source} to {destination} failed.", ex);
            return false;
        }            
    }
}
```

The tool running `FileHelper.TryCopy` copies files from a fileshare to a local server. The tool utilizes the TPL so there might be multiple tasks/threads calling this method. Recently, it started presenting this error:

> Copying file from FileShare to Local Server failed.
>   'System.IO.IOException: A device attached to the system is not functioning. 
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
>   at MyNameSpace.MyTool.Utilities.IO.FileManager.TryCopy(String source, String destination, Boolean overwrite) in ..\Utilities\IO\FileHelper.cs:line 21

I've investigated online and have found several suggestions: check drivers, check stale sessions that might be potentially locking the fileshare, and so on. I'm still not entirely sure what causes this though. What can I do on the application side of things? Retries? Throttling?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious and checked if the source and destination are / were available at the given point and time?

Comment: Depending on how clever your file sharing server is, you may be running into bandwidth issues or simply get cut off by the server because it is handling too many requests. Throttling seems like a good bet.

Comment: @Marco hi, the source is the fileshare, the destination is where the caller (i.e. the tool) is located

Comment: @globetrotter, that was not the question. You should compare system logs and application logs for the point and time when the exception happened to see if there is anything wrong with either the source or desitionation host. Like Timothy Groote said: Throttling for example, or solar flares

Comment: @Marco hehehe solar flares. "I flip up today's excuse card" :p